# Android Share via facebook, twitter, google plus

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, google-plus

Like timely, I have seen apps with share links such as google plus, facebook, and twitter. I can use these links in html and css, but I do not know how to implement them inside the app. Like Timely, it will open a popup with three choice buttons, and the user will click one and it would open the web page. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sending Simple Data to Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)